# In $\triangle ABC$ with $\angle C=90^\circ$, medians from $B$ and $C$ meet at a right angle. If $BC=8$, then find $BN$.

Tags: geometry

Please tell me shortcut of this question:

> In $\triangle ABC$, $\angle C=90^\circ$. $M$ and $N$ are the midpoints of sides $AB$ and $AC$, respectively. $CM$ and $BN$ intersect each other at $D$ and $\angle BDC= 90^\circ$. If $BC=8$cm, then what is the length of $BN$?

[(original problem image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veayS.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows about a problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or talking over your head. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) Since comments are easily overlooked, [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3518072/edit) to add details.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Because M and N are midpoints, D is the centroid, with BN : BD = 3:2. Note that
the triangles BCN and BCD are similar. Then,

$$\frac{BC}{BN}=\frac{BD}{BC}$$

Substitute $BD = \frac 23 BN$ to get

$$\frac23 BN^2 = BC^2$$

Thus,

$$BN = \sqrt{\frac32}\cdot BC = 4\sqrt6$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let $|BC|=a=8,\ |AC|=b,\ |AB|=c,\ |BN|=m_b,\ |CM|=m_c$.

Since $\angle BCA=90^\circ$ 
and $CM\perp BN$, we have two known conditions:
\begin{align}
a^2+b^2&=c^2
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
b^2+c^2&=5\,a^2
\tag{2}\label{2}
,
\end{align}

which imply

\begin{align} 
b^2&=2\,a^2
,\quad
c^2=3\,a^2
,
\end{align}

and we can use the known expression for the size of the median

\begin{align} 
m_b&=\tfrac12\,\sqrt{2\,a^2+2\,c^2-b^2}
=\frac{\sqrt6}2\,a
=4\,\sqrt6
.
\end{align}